# I want to pass the parameter from home page to another page using spring mvc framework?

Tags: java, spring

I had written a code for the passing the parameter but in the login page it is not displaying the parameter can anyone help me?My home page code as shown below

```
    <h1>
    <form:form action="./loginPage" method="GET" >
        <input type ="text" value="abc" id="name">
        <input type ="submit" value ="Login">

</form:form>
</h1>
```

my controller page:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Model model) {


    return "home";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/loginPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String redirect(@ModelAttribute("name")String name,BindingResult result,Model model) {
    model.addAttribute(name);

     if(result.hasErrors()){
            return "home";
        }else{
           model.addAttribute("name",name);
           return "loginPage";
        }

   }
```

My login page to display the parameter:

```
<h1>
    Welcome to login Page
</h1>
<p>The value is:${name}</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When collecting input, there are a couple of ways to go, I'll go over two options here:

1. You can use a command object and bind that as an attribute in which case you would have something like this:

   public class LoginForm {

   ```
   @NotNull(message="Name is required")
   private String name;

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
   ```

   }

In your controller you would:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method= { RequestMethod.POST } )
public String redirect(@ModelAttribute("LoginForm") @Valid LoginForm loginForm,  BindingResult bindingResult, Model model)  {
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        return "home";
    }

    model.addAttribute("name", loginForm.getName());
    return "loginPage";
}
```

In your JSP (with bootstrap classes) something like this, where you bind the form object to the form element which allows you to then bind the attribute "name" to the input field.

```
<form:form  method="post" 
            commandName="loginForm"
            action="/login" 
            role="form">

    <form:errors path="name" id="name-errors" element="div" cssClass="alert alert-danger" />
    <form:input path="name" cssClass="form-control" placeholder="Your name" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />

</form:form>
```

1. You can use request parameter binding to just pluck a field from a query string or form. However the downside is you can't use build in form validation and you want to redraw a form after an error you'll need to pass all the parameters back to repopulate it manually.I

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/loginPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String redirect(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false) String name, Model model) {
       if(name == null || name.length() == 0) {
           return "home";
       }
       model.addAttribute("name",name);
       return "loginPage";
   }
   ```

For what it looks like your trying to do I'd recommend you use the command object binding approach. Also if you are using spring MVC for authentication, you should take a look at spring security. While the configuration can be a little frustrating it does provide a standard way to handle authentication and authorization.

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.x/guides/hellomvc.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that Model is request scoped. You will have to use Sessions